# Finitness conditions under change of rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, free-modules, flatness

Let $R \to S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings, such that $S$ is finitely generated and projective $R$-module. Proof that if $A$ is a finitely presented $S$-module then $A$ is a finitely presented $R$-module.

Comment: As $R$ is projective it is flat over $S$ in particular tensoring with it is exact. So you can take the finite presentation of $S$ as cokernel of a map between finite free modules over $S$ and tensor it with $R$ to get literally a finite presentation over $R$.

Comment: But $R$ has no module structure over $S$

Comment: sorry, wrong way around. but you can do the same thing, just tensor over R. S is flat over R and so all should be golden. (mainly using that change of rings can be interpreted as tensoring)